# Ho to use Instabug InstabugInvocationEvent.SCREENSHOT without external storage permission?

Tags: android

When I try to setup Instabug bug reporting like this:

```
BugReporting.setInvocationEvents(
                    InstabugInvocationEvent.SHAKE,
                    InstabugInvocationEvent.SCREENSHOT
            );
```

The permission request alert is shown. And I don't understand why. Can't Instabug application use environment folders?

As described in documentation:
Generally, the permission request doesn't appear unless the user attempts to use any of the features requiring the permission. The only exception, if you set the invocation event to be Screenshot. Then, the storage permission will be requested when the application launches.

But is there any way to avoid this?